# What alternative I can use to SVG words cloud?

Tags: html, svg, html5-canvas

Recently, I've designed a word cloud in Illustrator for a customer. It uses around 5,000 people's names in white on a colored background on a logo path, and includes a few vector logos. Each name is ridiculously small, and we want to be able to search on the cloud and find our name.

We've put it online as a SVG with success - but a 20M file can cause problems!

So everything would be fine until we reach 10,000 visitors at the same time, and make all our servers crash and timeout everyone.

So what is our alternative to make this fast, easy for visitors to use, and latency free? We think about Canvas, but not sure if it's simple to make a words cloud with [really (thing about following a logo path)] custom shape.

Comment: That's a big file! Does it need to be that complex, though? I mean, is a word cloud with 5000 elements useful? If you really can't simplify it, and you think people will want to download it even at that size, consider hosting it on a CDN.

Comment: unfortunately, yes the word cloud can't be simplified. We actually use a jpg and invite visitors to click on it, to download the file. But our customer isn't happy about this solution.

Comment: Well, even if each name is a modest 2K in size, that's already 10M, which imo is still too large. Could you do this in Flash or JavaScript, so that the customer can drill down to the part of the cloud they are interested in, using some sort of hierarchy? They can't possibly want to read all 5,000 items on the full thing `;)`.

Comment: @halfer What kind of name is 2k in size?

Comment: @Marcin - I was assuming glyphs would be rendered to paths. But you're right, they should just be text elements.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you have 20Mb because the names are being stored/represented with paths. If you represent them as text, you will substantially reduce the size of the file, AND make it appropriately searchable.

Assuming 13 characters per name (including the space in between), UTF-8 encoding, and 10,000 names the names themselves should only take 127Kb. You may wish to experiment with transmitting the background of the SVG and the names (JSON?), and using a script to construct the cloud in the browser.

Edit: Even if you create a completely static SVG, representing the text as text will result in a substantial saving of space over the use of paths.

Comment: In illustrator you can prevent the text elements from being converted to paths in the save settings `Font Subsetting > None (Use system fonts)` http://i.stack.imgur.com/rAHmN.png